# Unable to send CSV/Text file via using sendgrid

Tags: email, csv, email-attachments, sendgrid

Am using sendgrid (2.2.2 version) in spring boot project to send an email containing an attachment (Requirement - to send a CSV file)

SendGrid.Email has three methods:

email.addAttachment (String name, String File ) - CSV file with name and filepath as content.

email.addAttachment(String name, File file ) - CSV/text file with comma separated content doesn't is not found to be attached with the mail.
However, a sample text file with some junk data is attached to the mail.

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Harsha

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: The  code am setting the attachment?

Comment: The code that isn't working.  Its hard to guess what is wrong without seeing what you have written